# reset() on Inputstream without mark()

Tags: java, inputstream

According to [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) it says that:

> `void reset()`
>
> Repositions this stream to the position at the time the `mark` method was last called on this input stream.

But what happens if `mark()` was never called? Will it reset to the beginning of the stream (which is what I want) or will it be undefined? Also when I look at the documentation for `markSupported()` it says:

> Tests if this input stream supports the `mark` and **reset** `methods`.

So this tests for reset as well, which indicates that reset might also not be supported. Is it safer in this case if I just close and reopen the stream in my own reset code?

Comment: Did you give it a try? ( Referring to "But what happens if mark() was never called?")

Comment: Trying some example against a particular implementation is not the same as working against the standard. And yes, I know that it currently works, but it might not work if I extend the class with another implementation.

Comment: I see, so you want to make the code independent of a particular Stream-Implementation, right? If I remember correctly, reset only makes sense if mark is supported. And I darkly remember reading that if it is supported and mark has not been called, then reset will either throw an IOException or rewind to the start.

Comment: Thanks. So I guess if `markSupported()` returns false, I should reopen. You should post this as an answer. :)

Comment: Did you consider reading the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset())? "f the method mark has not been called since the stream was created, or the number of bytes read from the stream since mark was last called is larger than the argument to mark at that last call, then an IOException might be thrown."

Comment: i read the documentation, but somehow I missed that I can scroll down and get additional information there, because the relevant info was already on the page I was looking in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset%28%29) provides an answer; unfortunately, it is not an unambiguous answer:

> The general contract of `reset` is:
>
> If the method markSupported returns `true`, then:
>
> - If the method mark has not been called since the stream was created, or the number of bytes read from the stream since mark was last called
>     is larger than the argument to mark at that last call, then an
>     `IOException` might be thrown.
> - If such an `IOException` is not thrown, then the stream is reset to a state such that all the bytes read since the most recent call to mark
>     (or since the start of the file, if mark has not been called) will be
>     resupplied to subsequent callers of the read method, followed by any
>     bytes that otherwise would have been the next input data as of the
>     time of the call to reset.
>
> If the method markSupported returns `false`, then:
>
> - The call to reset may throw an `IOException`.
> - If an `IOException` is not thrown, then the stream is reset to a fixed state that depends on the particular type of the input stream and how
>     it was created. The bytes that will be supplied to subsequent callers
>     of the read method depend on the particular type of the input stream.

In other words, if `markSupported()` returns `true` then the stream can either throw an `IOException` or behave as you want it to. If `markSupported()` returns `false` then it will either throw an exception or behave in an implementation-specific way.

In short, the interface contract makes no guarantee that the implementation will behave as you want it to. The safest thing seems to be to check for `markSupported()` and set a mark at the beginning of the input stream, if it is supported. If it is not supported, you need to either experiment to ensure the operation functions as expected or devise a means of recreating the stream.

Comment: At least [one](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/StringBufferInputStream.java#StringBufferInputStream.reset%28%29) library implementation resets to the beginning if no mark has been set.

Comment: @selig: Actually, that just resets to the beginning regardless of any call to mark (and for that implementation, `markSupported()` returns `false`). This is a possible behaviour according to the documented contract, it just isn't guaranteed for all implementations.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of `reset()` without calling `mark()` isn't very stricly specified, but from the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset()):

> The general contract of reset is:
>
> - If the method markSupported returns true, then:
> - If the method mark has not been called since the stream was created, or the number of bytes read from the stream since mark was last called is larger than the argument to mark at that last call, then an IOException might be thrown.
> - If such an IOException is not thrown, then the stream is reset to a state such that all the bytes read since the most recent call to mark (or since the start of the file, if mark has not been called) will be resupplied to subsequent callers of the read method, followed by any bytes that otherwise would have been the next input data as of the time of the call to reset.

Comment: This answer was downvoted because..? :-( I agree that the accepted answer is more elaborate, but I don't see anything inaccurate or false here...